# How to limit the range of the variable in equation

Tags: equation-solving

Of course, we can limit the domain to `Integers`. But I want to limit the domain to `0` or `1` in this equation

```
2 x11 + 8 x12 + 6 x13 - 4 x14 + 7 x15 + 3 x16 - 5 x17 + 4 x18 + 
 2 x19 + 2 x20 + 10 x21 + 10 x22 + 4 x23 + 3 x24 + 2 x25 + 2 x26 - 
 5 x27 + 9 x28 + 6 x29 + 9 x30 + 7 x31 - x32 - 4 x33 - 3 x34 + x35 + 
 2 x36 + x37 - 2 x38 - x39 + x40 == 39
```

I mean All `{x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x30, x31, x32, x33, x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39, x40}` is `0` or `1`. How to solve this equation?

Comment: What are you going to do with the solutions? Probably generating all of the solutions and then filtering is not the best approach.

Comment: @CarlWoll Actually I hope to find all possible combination in list `{2,8,6,-4,7,3,-5,4,2,2,10,10,4,3,2,2,-5,9,6,9,7,-1,-4,-3,1,2,1,-2,-1,1}`. Then I encouter this problem..

Answer (score 11):

You could use symmetry of your equation to "factorize" problem of finding solutions. Since some variables have same coefficients, your equation is invariant with respect to permutations of those variables. You could group them, and replace with lower number of variables, representing sums of original variables.

$n_i$ variables associated with $i$-th coefficient naively contribute $2^{n_i}$ combinations of $0$ and $1$ to possible solutions. One variable representing their sum contribute only $n_i+1$ possible values. Splitting value of combined variable to original variables, after finding solution to reduced equation, is trivial.

With your equation we have:

```
eq = 2 x11 + 8 x12 + 6 x13 - 4 x14 + 7 x15 + 3 x16 - 5 x17 + 4 x18 + 
    2 x19 + 2 x20 + 10 x21 + 10 x22 + 4 x23 + 3 x24 + 2 x25 + 2 x26 - 
    5 x27 + 9 x28 + 6 x29 + 9 x30 + 7 x31 - x32 - 4 x33 - 3 x34 + 
    x35 + 2 x36 + x37 - 2 x38 - x39 + x40 == 39;

coeffToVars = KeySort@GroupBy[
  Replace[List @@ eq[[1]], c_. x_ :> {c, x}, {1}],
  First -> Last
]
varGroups = Values@coeffToVars;
(* <|-5 -> {x17, x27}, -4 -> {x14, x33}, -3 -> {x34}, -2 -> {x38},
     -1 -> {x32, x39}, 1 -> {x35, x37, x40}, 2 -> {x11, x19, x20, x25, x26, x36},
     3 -> {x16, x24}, 4 -> {x18, x23}, 6 -> {x13, x29}, 7 -> {x15, x31},
     8 -> {x12}, 9 -> {x28, x30}, 10 -> {x21, x22}|> *)
```

Naively there are `2^Length@Variables@eq[[1]] (* 1 073 741 824 *)` possible combinations. After grouping variables we are down to `Times @@ (Length /@ varGroups + 1) (* 4 408 992 *)`. Reduced problem is small enough that 1 GB of memory is enough to perform brute-force search of solutions.

```
possibleSols = Tuples[Range[0, Length@#]& /@ varGroups]; // MaxMemoryUsed
(* 493 810 136 *)
possibleSols // Length
(* 4 408 992 *)

sols = Pick[possibleSols, possibleSols.Keys@coeffToVars, eq[[2]]]; // MaxMemoryUsed
(* 564 351 608 *)
sols // Length
(* 105 929 *)
```

There are $105\,929$ solutions of reduced problem.

To recover solutions in terms of original variables we construct tuples of permutations of lists with $k_i$ ones and $n_i - k_i$ zeros, where $n_i$ is number of variables associated with $i$-th coefficient, and $k_i$ is value of $i$-th variable of reduced problem in given solution.

```
ungroupedSolutions // ClearAll
ungroupedSolutions[varGroups_ : {__List}] := With[
  {
    lengths = Length /@ varGroups,
    ord = Ordering[Join @@ varGroups]
  },
  Developer`ToPackedArray[Join @@@ Tuples[
    Permutations /@ MapThread[
      Join[ConstantArray[1, #1], ConstantArray[0, #2 - #1]]&,
      {#, lengths}
    ]
  ]][[All, ord]]&
]

ungroupedSolutionsNumber // ClearAll
ungroupedSolutionsNumber[varGroups_ : {__List}] := With[
  {lengths = Length /@ varGroups},
  Times @@ Binomial[lengths, #]&
]
```

Let's choose one of solutions of reduced problem and construct all corresponding solutions to original problem:

```
sols[[13784]]
(* {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1} *)
tmpSols = ungroupedSolutions[varGroups]@%;
tmpSols // Length
(* 240 *)
```

above reduced solution corresponds to $240$ solutions of original problem. Let's check that they all solve original equation:

```
And @@ (eq /. (Thread[Sort@Variables@eq[[1]] -> #] & /@ tmpSols))
(* True *)
```

Let's count all solutions of original equation:

```
ungroupedSolutionsNumber@varGroups /@ sols // Total
(* 30 174 150 *)
```

there are $30\,174\,150$ of them.

Comment: That full count could be done using some Laurent polynomial algebra. With `poly` as the original left-hand-side, we proceed: `In[1320]:= p2 = 1 + Apply[List, poly] /. a_Integer*b_ :> b^a;
p3 = Apply[Times, p2] /. Thread[Variables[p2] -> xx];
Coefficient[p3, xx^39]

Out[1322]= 30174150`

Comment: Crazy, man!!!!!

Comment: +1 Impressive thinking.

Answer (score 7):

**Restricting Variables to Specific Values**

Restricting the variables to 0 or 1 might more easily be done using regions:

```
poly = 2 x11 + 8 x12 + 6 x13 - 4 x14 + 7 x15 + 3 x16 - 5 x17 + 4 x18 +
    2 x19 + 2 x20 + 10 x21 + 10 x22 + 4 x23 + 3 x24 + 2 x25 + 2 x26 - 
    5 x27 + 9 x28 + 6 x29 + 9 x30 + 7 x31 - x32 - 4 x33 - 3 x34 + x35 + 
    2 x36 + x37 - 2 x38 - x39 + x40;

vars = Variables @ poly;

cond = Element[ vars, Point @ { {0}, {1} } ]; (* a point-set *)
```

`cond` can then be used within `NSolve`, `FindInstance` and the like.

To demonstrate this I will use Ulrich Neumanns simple example:

```
NSolve[
   {
      x1 + 2 x2 - x3 == 0,
      Element[ {x1, x2, x3 }, Point @ { {0}, {1} } ] (* a point-set *)
   },
   { x1, x2, x3 }
]
(* {{x1 -> {0.}, x2 -> {0.}, x3 -> {0.}}, {x1 -> {1.}, x2 -> {0.}, 
   x3 -> {1.}}} *)
```

Unfortunatley for the OP's problem both `FindInstance[ poly == 39 && cond, vars, Integers, 1]` and `NSolve[ poly == 39 && cond, vars ]` crash Mathematica on my machine  (Win 10 64Bit, 24 GB Ram) - careful if you try out!

**But...**

**Update:  Solutions to the Problem**

There is a way to solve the OP's problem though:

```
rules = Thread[ vars -> Boole /@ vars ];
polyBoolean = poly /. rules;
```

We have now put the problem into a form, where Boolean variables can be used. We can now use `FindInstance`:

```
sol = First @ FindInstance[ polyBoolean == 39, vars, Booleans ];
sol01 = Boole /@ sol
```

> {x11 -> 1, x12 -> 1, x13 -> 1, x14 -> 1, x15 -> 1, x16 -> 1, x17 -> 1,
>     x18 -> 1, x19 -> 1, x20 -> 1, x21 -> 1, x22 -> 1, x23 -> 1, 
>    x24 -> 1, x25 -> 1, x26 -> 0, x27 -> 1, x28 -> 0, x29 -> 0, x30 -> 0,
>     x31 -> 0, x32 -> 1, x33 -> 1, x34 -> 1, x35 -> 1, x36 -> 0, 
>    x37 -> 0, x38 -> 1, x39 -> 1, x40 -> 0}

Testing the solution reveals:

```
poly /. sol01
```

> 39

And there is much more:

```
FindInstance[ polyBoolean == 39, vars, Booleans, 1000 (* or higher *) ]
```

will find many more solutions.

Comment: Tricky, I didn't know point-set domain.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to specify the condition on a variable that it be either zero or 1 is to observe that the square of the variable must equal itself, e.g. x^2==x has only solutions x=0 and x=1. So we could add these conditions to the solution. Here is a small example:

```
Solve[Flatten[{2 x[1] + 3 x[2] - 2 x[3] == 3, 
      x[#]^2 == x[#] & /@ Range[3]}], x[#] & /@ Range[3]]
{{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 0}, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 1}}
```

which are indeed the only solutions for this toy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem in the way I do it examplary  for simpler problem:

```
NSolve[{x1 + 2 x2 - x3 == 0, 
0 <= x1 <= 1, 0 <= x2 <= 1, 0 <= x3 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers]
(* {{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: This works, but I wonder if there's a better way if one has a lot of variables like in the OP's example.

Comment: Sorry, It can solve my equation in post?

Comment: @J.M. Eventually the size of the solution set overwhelms any clever tactic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Could you tell me some samples?

Answer (score 0):

```
 eq = 2 x11 + 8 x12 + 6 x13 - 4 x14 + 7 x15 + 3 x16 - 5 x17 + 4 x18 + 
   2 x19 + 2 x20 + 10 x21 + 10 x22 + 4 x23 + 3 x24 + 2 x25 + 2 x26 - 
   5 x27 + 9 x28 + 6 x29 + 9 x30 + 7 x31 - x32 - 4 x33 - 3 x34 + 
   x35 + 2 x36 + x37 - 2 x38 - x39 + x40;

var = Variables@eq;
 NSolve[eq == 0 && And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 & /@ var), var, Integers]
```

There are more than 600k solutions!

Comment: I don't know why this approach doesn't work `NSolve[eq == 0 && var \[Element] {0, 1}, var]` It would be nice if it worked.